# ERROR OS=Windows and the assembly descriptor contains a *nix-specific root-relative-reference (starting with slash) /

Tags: windows, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I use maven-assembly-plugin v2.5.3 and get the following error

```
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: src/main/assembly/distributive.zip.xml
[ERROR] OS=Windows and the assembly descriptor contains a *nix-specific root-relative-reference (starting with slash) /
```

But the build is SUCCESSFUL. What does this error mean?

I've found a mention of it in [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-775).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

simplest solution to prevent that warning is:

```xml
<fileSets>
  <fileSet>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <outputDirectory/>
  </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

or an other solution is:

```xml
<fileSets>
  <fileSet>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <outputDirectory>./</outputDirectory>
  </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

and it shows that something should be fixed.

Comment: Well, it looks like it's still not fixed.

Comment: Yes, either way it's still not fixed.

Answer (score 13):

This is probably because of Linux-like `<outputDirectory>`:

```xml
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>
```

Specify the empty `<outputDirectory>` or try `./`.